# A simple .htaccess rewrite rule is not working as expected if php files are requested

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite all requests directed at files/folders in the root directory to a subdirectory called "Web". This simple .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Web
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

is working fine for most scenarios, but, unexpectedly, php files directly accessed through the browser are still being looked for in the root directory, even though the RewriteRule does not discriminate between file types (it get's weirder though, see below). With this, I'm getting the following results...

Working:

- Directories: **domain.com/test/** will correctly rewrite to **domain.com/Web/test/** independent of whether the folder exists in either the root or the Web directory or both, as expected
- All tested non-php file types, e.g. **domain.com/test.txt** correctly rewrite to **domain.com/Web/test.txt**, again independent of whether the file exists in either the root or the Web directory or both, as expected (i.e. either displaying the file that I placed in the Web directory or throwing the expected 404 error message for not finding the file in the subfolder if it does not exist)

HOWEVER, trying to open php files in the browser (e.g. **domain.com/test.php**) results in the following, unexpected behavior:

- If the php file DOES exist in the Web subfolder but does NOT exist in the root directory (default scenario), I'm getting an unexpected 404 "The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server", i.e. **the server is looking for the file in the root directory, ignoring the .htaccess rewrite**, even though the rewrite clearly is working for other file types, see above
- If the php file does NOT exist in the Web subfolder but DOES exist in the root directory, I'm getting a 404 "The requested URL **/Web/** test.php was not found on this server.", i.e. NOW the server is trying to open the file from the expected subfolder-location.
- If the php file DOES exist in the Web subfolder AND in the root directory, the server displays the test.php file version that was placed in the subfolder.

My conclusions are:

- all non-php file types are behaving according to the .htaccess file, independently of whether the requested files/folders exist in the root directory and/or the subfolder - the behavior is always as expected
- all requests for php files follow the htaccess rule ONLY IF a corresponding file exists in the root directory, even though the file residing in the root directory is never actually served to the browser, in accordance with the rewrite rule

I find this extremely weird, since there's no RewriteCond to specify absence or presence of the file. The Regex clearly triggers for php files, but only in a complicated, counterintuitive fashion. The one RewriteCond I do have only prevents infinite looping.

I have tried adding RewriteCond's that match both absence and presence of file, but it did not fix the file problem.

Does anyone have an idea? Why are php-files treated differently from all other types in this scenario?